# Magento checkout Tax problem

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shopping-cart, shipping-tax

In My website checkout tax price not included but it showing correctly in shopping cart page

**Shopping Cart:**
[image]

**Checkout**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got answer in my question

In Shopping cart page want to show subtotal without tax then go to

```
/app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/tax/checkout
```

Find this

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($this->getTotal()->getValue(), false, false);
```

and change into

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
```

No need to set **Exclude tax**